# Website images recently disappeared

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have a php file, and I am fairly novice at website development, but I've been helping a friend out.  On the site we had some images that have been there for months, and recently they disappeared.  I know the path to the images is still correct, and nothing with the coding has changed.  Any ideas on why this could be broken? The pictures were in the div class = "graphicbuttons_cont"

```
$poli_more = do_shortcode('[pl_modal title="Buy & Sell" type="tab_links" label="<img class=\'\' title=\'Buy & Sell\' src=\'/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/buysell_icon.png\'  /><br /><span>Buy & Sell</span>"]{27}[/pl_modal]');
        $feed_back = do_shortcode('[pl_modal title="Feedback" type="tab_links" label="<img class=\'\' title=\'Feedback\' src=\'/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/feedback_icon.png\'  /><br /><span>Feedback</span>"][gravityform id=4 title=false ajax=true field_values=\'store_page_id={28}\'][/pl_modal]');
        $email_list = do_shortcode('[pl_modal title="email list" label="<img class=\'\' title=\'email list\' src=\'/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/email_icon.png\'  /><br /><span>email list</span>"][gravityform id=1 title=false][/pl_modal]');
        $desc_template = '<div id="header_container">' .
                            '<h1 style="text-transform: uppercase;" class="entry-title">' .
                                'Game on {0}' .
                            '</h1>' .
                        '</div>' .

                        '<div class="store_banner_class">' .
                            '<a href="javascript:void(0)"><img style="height: 145px; width: 100%;" src="{33}" class="banner_img" /></a>' .
                        '</div>' .

                        '<div class="graphicbuttons_area">' .
                            '<div class="graphicbuttons_cont">' .
                                $poli_more.
                            '</div>' .
                            '<div class="graphicbuttons_cont">' .
                                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr={25}&daddr={26}" target="_blank">
                                    <img title="Directions" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/getdirection_icon.png"  /><br /><span>Directions</span>
                                </a>' .
                            '</div>' .
                            '<div class="graphicbuttons_cont">' .
                                '<a title="Follow " href="{29}" target="_blank">
                                    <img title="Follow" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/fblikeus_icon.png"  /><br /><span>Follow </span>
                                </a>' .
                            '</div>' .
                            '<div class="graphicbuttons_cont">' .
                                $email_list.
                            '</div>' .
                            '<div class="graphicbuttons_cont">' .
                                '<a title="Review " href="{30}" target="_blank">
                                    <img title="Review" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/gplus_icon.png"  /><br /><span>Review </span>
                                </a>' .
                            '</div>' .
                            '<div class="graphicbuttons_cont">' .
                                $feed_back.
                            '</div>' .
                        '</div>' .
```

Here's the style.css page,

```
#main_container {
padding: 30px;
background: #f1f1ef;
margin-top: -15px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#store_image_container {
float: left;
width: 33%;
}
#gen_info_container {
float: left;
width: 61%;
margin-left: 60px;
}

#header_container h1 {
text-transform: uppercase;
float: left;
line-height: 32px;
font-size: 24px;
color: #ffffff;
padding-left: 10px;
}

#header_container {
background-color: #474647;
padding: 5px;
height: 32px;
margin-top: 20px; 
}
#store_image_container img {
margin-bottom: 20px;

}
#data_gen_info {
margin-bottom: 22px;
clear: both;
}
#label_gen_info,  .social-icon a {
font-size: 12px;
color: #37a8ab;
}
#label_notefrmowner {
font-size: 22px;
color: #B98BBF;
}
#data_notefrmowner {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#data_gen_info div table, #data_notefrmowner div table {
border: 0px;
}
#data_gen_info div table tr td, #data_notefrmowner div table tr td {
border: 0px;
}
#map_slideout {
display: none;
height: 410px;
}
#menu_cont {
float: right;
margin-right: 20px;
line-height: 32px;
}
#slider_button {
z-index: 1035;
height: 20px;
}
 #click_btn {
background: url("viewstorelocator.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
padding: 0 196px 30px 0;
position: absolute;
right: 15px;
top: 0;
}
.tab_links, .tab_links:hover {
color: #ffffff;
margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;     display: inline-block;
}
#sl_div img {
max-width: none;
}
#directionurl {
background: #37A8AB;
color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: none;
text-shadow: none;
border: 0px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 4px 10px;
font-size: 12px;
}


.social-icon {
float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
width: 31%;
}
.social-icon a {
color: #37A8AB;
}
.social-icon span {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.social-icon .social-icon-inner {
height: 130px;
}

.store_banner_class{
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.banner_img{
height: 330px;
width: 100%;
}

.graphicbuttons_area{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F1F1EF;
padding: 20px 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.graphicbuttons_cont{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 15px;
}

.graphicbuttons_cont span{
color: #37A8AB;
font-family: "Montserrat";
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

Comment: Have you changed the IP or server..??Its not the problem with the CSS

Comment: With an instance like this, seeing the site would probably be the most helpful. I see this is a wordpress installation, has wordpress been updated or any plugins that may affect this area updated?

Comment: Can you give me the url to that page?

Comment: provide jsfiddle, that will be helpful to solve your query

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to put something from a site this large in jsfiddle.  Since it has all of the images and files in multiple locations it would take me a while.  If it's necessary I'll figure it out, but I was really hoping I was overlooking something small, and had just been looking at it for too long.  But now this morning with a fresh set of eyes, I still am not seeing a problem.  It's identical code to the site that's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your CSS and everything to do with your image locations...your urls in your php code are `/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/fblikeus_icon.png` and the url being printed in your live site are `/portugal/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/fblikeus_icon.png`

I would suggest figuring out why there is a discrepancy there.  When I take /portugal/ out of your paths in Chrome's dev tools...your images show up fine.

Comment: You were correct.  As it turns out there appears to be a permissions problem somewhere in that path, but not with the actual folder being used, which makes perfect sense, but I didn't think to check that.  When I changed the path, everything worked perfectly.  Thanks!